# Keyboard input using stdio.StandardIO in twisted python

Tags: python, twisted, keyboard-input

I have a doubt in twisted python related to my multiclient chat server program.

that is, when we give input from keyboard using [`stdio.StandardIO`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.stdio.StandardIO.html), where it is stored when we run the reactor? Can anybody give me the answer, please..

Answer (score 7):

`twisted.internet.stdio.StandardIO` doesn't "store" data anywhere.  It is a transport which you associate with a protocol.  The protocol you associate with it can do anything you want with the data delivered to it.

You can find two examples of using `StandardIO` in the Twisted documentation, https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/stdin.py and https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/stdiodemo.py.

Comment: Jean-Paul, One more help, please. Could you please give me an example for this as per the above answer.

Comment: Maybe you should tick this answer as correct if it answers to your need correctly