# Twisted Python - IRC Client

Tags: python, client, twisted, irc

first question here.

So for a club at school we are working on making a IRC client in Python and Twisted.

So I take the example bot that twisted gives you. I've managed to get it connected to a irc channel, and it logs.

I know I've probably gotta use 2 threads to have both reading from the server and input simultaneous, which I can achieve, but only if it command line input. Mind you it is still logging the data from the channel at the same time.

So to do this I used: `d = threads.deferToThread(aSillyBlockingMethod)`

Which calls my `raw_input()` loop.

My problem lies in not being able to figure out how to change this from just typing into and printing form the commandline; to being able to actually send messages to the irc server for other people to read.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a novice python programmer and don't know too much web stuff; like protocols, ports, and stuff like that but I am slowly picking them up. If anyone knows of an easier way to do this let me know please I am not committed to using Twisted.

Here is my code, or rather the modified bot I'm tinkering with:

```
# twisted imports
from twisted.words.protocols import irc
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.internet import threads

# system imports
import time, sys

class MessageLogger:
    """
    An independent logger class (because separation of application
    and protocol logic is a good thing).
    """
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def log(self, message):
        """Write a message to the file."""
        timestamp = time.strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", time.localtime(time.time()))
        self.file.write('%s %s\n' % (timestamp, message))
        self.file.flush()

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()


class LogBot(irc.IRCClient):
    """A logging IRC bot."""

    nickname = "twistedbot"

    def connectionMade(self):
        irc.IRCClient.connectionMade(self)
        self.logger = MessageLogger(open(self.factory.filename, "a"))
        self.logger.log("[connected at %s]" % 
                        time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())))

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        irc.IRCClient.connectionLost(self, reason)
        self.logger.log("[disconnected at %s]" % 
                        time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())))
        self.logger.close()


    # callbacks for events

    def signedOn(self):
        """Called when bot has succesfully signed on to server."""
        self.join(self.factory.channel)

    def joined(self, channel):
        """This will get called when the bot joins the channel."""
        self.logger.log("[I have joined %s]" % channel)

    def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
        """This will get called when the bot receives a message."""
        user = user.split('!', 1)[0]
        self.logger.log("<%s> %s" % (user, msg))

        # Check to see if they're sending me a private message
        if channel == self.nickname:
            msg = "It isn't nice to whisper!  Play nice with the group."
            self.msg(user, msg)
            return

        # Otherwise check to see if it is a message directed at me
        if msg.startswith(self.nickname + ":"):
            msg = "%s: I am a log bot" % user
            self.msg(channel, msg)
            self.logger.log("<%s> %s" % (self.nickname, msg))

    def action(self, user, channel, msg):
        """This will get called when the bot sees someone do an action."""
        user = user.split('!', 1)[0]
        self.logger.log("* %s %s" % (user, msg))

    # irc callbacks

    def irc_NICK(self, prefix, params):
        """Called when an IRC user changes their nickname."""
        old_nick = prefix.split('!')[0]
        new_nick = params[0]
        self.logger.log("%s is now known as %s" % (old_nick, new_nick))


    # For fun, override the method that determines how a nickname is changed on
    # collisions. The default method appends an underscore.
    def alterCollidedNick(self, nickname):
        """
        Generate an altered version of a nickname that caused a collision in an
        effort to create an unused related name for subsequent registration.
        """
        return nickname + '^'


def aSillyBlockingMethod(self):
        import time
        while True:
            msg = raw_input()
            print msg



class LogBotFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    """A factory for LogBots.

    A new protocol instance will be created each time we connect to the server.
    """

    def __init__(self, channel, filename):
        self.channel = channel
        self.filename = filename

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        p = LogBot()
        p.factory = self
        return p

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        """If we get disconnected, reconnect to server."""
        connector.connect()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "connection failed:", reason
        reactor.stop()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize logging
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

    # create factory protocol and application
    f = LogBotFactory("#goon.squad.dev", "test.txt")

    # connect factory to this host and port
    reactor.connectTCP("irc.freenode.net", 6667, f)

    #Use this to keep user input open
    d = threads.deferToThread(aSillyBlockingMethod)

    # run bot
    reactor.run()
```

--TyrZaraki

Comment: To clarify - you want `aSillyBlockingMethod` to translate the `raw_input` into actually sending a message?

Comment: Yeah that method should be named something like send_msg, but ultimately yes I need a method that can be used in a second thread to send messages to the irc server.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me - I haven't messed around with Twisted in a while.  However, my understanding is that it's an event framework, and the simplest way to handle this would be to allow Twisted to handle the user IO.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299896/keyboard-input-using-stdio-standardio-in-twisted-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know I've probably gotta use 2 threads to have both reading from the server and input simultaneous, which I can achieve, but only if it command line input. Mind you it is still logging the data from the channel at the same time.

Actually, it's not necessary to use two threads for this.  A major strength of Twisted is doing I/O without using threads.  The [question and answer Michael linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299896/keyboard-input-using-stdio-standardio-in-twisted-python) talk about Twisted's non-threaded support for interacting with standard input and standard output via `twisted.internet.stdio.StandardIO`.

> My problem lies in not being able to figure out how to change this from just typing into and printing form the commandline; to being able to actually send messages to the irc server for other people to read.

`IRCClient` has a method for sending messages to the IRC server - the sample code you included in your question even uses this method already, `IRCClient.msg`.  All you need to do is call it.

Your threaded code could change like this to do so (again, threads are unnecessary, but in the interest of **just** showing you how to send a message from your input handling code, I'll base this part of the answer on threads, to avoid other changes to the code which might make the answer harder to understand.  You **do not** need threads to do this.):

```
def aSillyBlockingMethod(bot):
    import time
    while True:
        msg = raw_input()
        bot.threadSafeMsg("#bottest", msg)


class LogBot(irc.IRCClient):
    """A logging IRC bot."""

    nickname = "twistedbot"

    def connectionMade(self):
        irc.IRCClient.connectionMade(self)
        self.logger = MessageLogger(open(self.factory.filename, "a"))
        self.logger.log("[connected at %s]" % 
                        time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())))

        # The bot is now connected.  Start reading input here.
        # Pass a reference to this protocol instance, so that
        # messages can be sent to this protocol instance.
        deferToThread(aSillyBlockingMethod, self)


    # Define a helper function for aSillyBlockingMethod to use.
    # Since aSillyBlockingMethod runs in a thread, it cannot just call
    # IRCClient.msg, since that method - like almost all methods in Twisted -
    # is not thread-safe.  Instead it must call this thread-safe wrapper.
    def threadSafeMsg(self, channel, message):
        reactor.callFromThread(self.msg, channel, message)
```

Notice that all that's happening here is that `aSillyBlockingMethod` is calling a method on `LogBot`.  The thread-safe wrapper would not be necessary when using `StandardIO`, since that eliminates the need for threads.

Comment: Okay if I try to change the aSillyBlocking method to call IRCClient.msg, it allows me to type in a message, but then the input locks up and doesn't send the message.

Comment: Also it turns out there is a bug in Twisted when using StandardIO in Windows.